# cordova-plugin-camera is not working on android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am following https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cordova/cordova_camera.htm this tutorial to used native camera functionality using Cordova.Below is my javascript code

```
 onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        //alert("test");
        document.getElementById("cameraTakePicture").addEventListener("click", cameraGetPicture);
        function cameraGetPicture() {
           alert("test");
           navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
              destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
             // sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
           });
           alert("test2");
           function onSuccess(imageURL) {
              alert('onSuccess: ' + imageURL);
              var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
              image.src = imageURL;
           }

           function onFail(message) {
              alert('Failed because: ' + message);
           }

        }
    },
```

when I run this app in **PhoneGap Desktop** application it showing **choose file** option properly in the browser.below is my console output

**adding proxy for Camera
 Received Event: deviceready**

but when I build APK using PhoneGap build and installed on Android phone nothing is happening.I am not able to debug code.

Comment: have you installed the plugin? the tutorial seems wrong, it should be `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`. But if you are using phonegap build you should add it in the config.mxl

Comment: Yes, I installed a plugin using Cordova cli command.and also added in config.xml - <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^3.0.0" /> and plugin name in tutorial is wrong i corrected it in my code